# Extremum of a weird array in numpy (python3)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
ar=[[[678,701]],
 [[680,702]],
 [[674,710]],
 ...]
```

I have to find extrema for each of the column (i.e., for these 678,680,674... and for 701,702,710,... independently).

I tried to access these columns with something like this:

`ar[:][0][0]` or `ar[:][0][1]`

but it turned out, that the Python understood `ar[:][0]` just the same as `ar[0]`, and because of that I don't know any way to prevent from using loops. Are there still any sophisticated technique to do that?

Comment: Take a look here, in particular the examples of *multidimensional* indexing: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the extrema along particular axes, you can use [the `axis` parameter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html):

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([[[678,701]],
 [[680,702]],
 [[674,710]],
])

print ar.max(axis=0)  #  [[680 710]]
print ar.max(axis=0)  #  [[674 701]]
```

To slice out the two columns, you can use:

```
print ar[:,0,0]       # [678 680 674]
print ar[:,0,1]       # [701 702 710]
```

Comment: Thanks, the slicing part is exactly what I needed